# How to move the text inside the canvas like the text bar animated?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas

I'm drawing canvas and   have put in some shapes and text and I want to move the text inside the canvas  like the text bar animated from left to right
As you can see, when I'm moving the text is moving not like it supposed to be.

How can I fix it?

```js
<script>
   var pointX, pointY , w , h ;

var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
c.width = window.innerWidth;
         c.height = window.innerHeight;
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width,ctx.canvas.height);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle='red';
    ctx.strokeRect(10,0,720,576);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle='grey';
    ctx.fillRect(10,525,720,50);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.beginPath();
    var start = 10;
 setInterval(function(){
 
 start += 4;
 ctx.font = "30px Arial";
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
     ctx.textAlign = "left";
    ctx.fillText("Hello World",start, 560);  
  }, 40);
ctx.closePath();
     pointX = 690;
     pointY = 550;
     w = 30;
    h = 20;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle='red';
    ctx.strokeRect(pointX,pointY,w,h);
    ctx.closePath();
 
</script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
        <script src ="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" ></script>
        <link href ="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src ="js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name = "viewport" content = "width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0"/>


        </head>
<body dir="rtl"  id="tbodyid">
      
              <canvas id="myCanvas" width="1050" height="1050"  class="col-12 col-s-12" >
                </canvas>
</body>



</html>
```

Comment: Inside your `setInterval` function add `ctx.clearRect(0,0,c.width,c.height)`. Also I would recomend using `requestAnimationFrame` instead of `setInterval`

Comment: When I add it inside the  setInterval function the text moves but deletes all the shapes that I draw.  I want the shapes to remain as they are just moving the text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I've commented, inside your `setInterval` function you should add `ctx.clearRect(0,0,c.width,c.height)`. Also you have to redraw everything else. So I've putted your shapes inside functions, and I'm calling those functions inside `setInterval` too.

```js
var pointX, pointY , w , h ;

var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
c.width = 1000;
c.height = 650;
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width,ctx.canvas.height);

function drawShape1(){
  ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle='red';
    ctx.strokeRect(10,0,720,576);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle='grey';
    ctx.fillRect(10,525,720,50);
    ctx.closePath();
}

function drawShape2(){
     pointX = 690;
     pointY = 550;
     w = 30;
    h = 20;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle='red';
    ctx.strokeRect(pointX,pointY,w,h);
    ctx.closePath();
}
    

    var start = 10;
 
setInterval(function(){
 ctx.clearRect(0,0,c.width,c.height)
 drawShape1() 
 start += 4;
 ctx.font = "30px Arial";
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
     ctx.textAlign = "left";
    ctx.fillText("Hello World",start, 560); 
  drawShape2() 
  }, 40);
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="1000" height="650"  class="col-12 col-s-12" ></canvas>
```

However if you want to try using `requestAnimationFrame` instead of `setInterval` this is how to do it:
Since `requestAnimationFrame` runs at 60 frames per sec I've changed `start += 4;` to `start += 2;`

```js
var pointX, pointY , w , h ;

var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
c.width = 1000;
c.height = 650;
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width,ctx.canvas.height);

function drawShape1(){
  ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle='red';
    ctx.strokeRect(10,0,720,576);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle='grey';
    ctx.fillRect(10,525,720,50);
    ctx.closePath();
}

function drawShape2(){
     pointX = 690;
     pointY = 550;
     w = 30;
    h = 20;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle='red';
    ctx.strokeRect(pointX,pointY,w,h);
    ctx.closePath();
}
    

    var start = 10;
 
function frame(){
 requestAnimationFrame(frame)
 ctx.clearRect(0,0,c.width,c.height)
 drawShape1() 
 start += 2;
 ctx.font = "30px Arial";
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
     ctx.textAlign = "left";
    ctx.fillText("Hello World",start, 560); 
  drawShape2() 
  }

frame()
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="1050" height="1050"  class="col-12 col-s-12" >
                </canvas>
```

Comment: I have asked the question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54496715/when-you-click-on-the-rectangle-inside-the-canvas-becomes-full-screen-of-all-th

Answer (score 1):

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="1050" height="1050"  class="col-12 col-s-12" >
                </canvas>
<script>
var pointX, pointY , w , h ;

var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
c.width = 1000;
c.height = 650;
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width,ctx.canvas.height);

function drawShape1(){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle='red';
    ctx.strokeRect(10,0,720,70);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle='gold';
    ctx.fillRect(10,10,720,50);
    ctx.closePath();
}

function drawShape2(){
     pointX = 690;
     pointY = 30;
     w = 30;
    h = 20;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle='red';
    ctx.strokeRect(pointX,pointY,w,h);
    ctx.closePath();
}
    

    var start = 10;
 
function frame(){
 requestAnimationFrame(frame)
 ctx.clearRect(0,0,c.width,c.height)
 drawShape1() 
 start += 2;
 ctx.font = "30px Arial";
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
     ctx.textAlign = "left";
    ctx.fillText("Hello World",start, 50); 
    if (start > 576) start = 0;
  drawShape2() 
  }

frame()
</script>
```